# Yii2 login not working properly on remote server

Tags: php, authentication, session, yii2, yii2-validation

I have a login problem on the remote server. I followed the error and discovered that the user is  logged in
this returns true in the LoginForm and at this level, I have the user

```
Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0)
```

However, at the controller when the login action receives true and redirects to the profile page, the latter shows null for

```
var_dump(\Yii::$app->user->identity);
```

I tried using DbSession, but the table also has null for the user_id.

Can anyone please help me to solve this issue, I have been working on it for the past 3 days.

Here are some samples of my code

```
public function actionLogin() {
    $login = new LoginForm('app');

    if ($login->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $login->login()) {
        $this->redirect(['/profile']);
    }
    return $this->render('login', [
        'login' => $login,
    ]);
}
```

profile controller

```
public function actionIndex() {
        var_dump(\Yii::$app->user->identity); // here i get null
        die();
    $dashboard = new Dashboard();
    return $this->render('index', [
        'dashboard' => $dashboard,
    ]);
}
```

common main conf

```
    'session' =>
    [
        'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
    ],
```

frontend conf

```
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
    ],
    'session' => [
        'name' => 'app-frontend',
    ],
```

Comment: have you tried running the `requirements.php` on the server, it is provided with the yii2 framework and is available on the root directory of your project, can you login via ssh and run that file through the terminal by typing `php requirements.php` and paste the output in your question,and you should define it on the frontend and backend separately for the session components, and not in `common/config`

Comment: and your configurations for the session component should look like `'session' => [
            'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
            'class' => 'yii\web\DbSession',
            'gCProbability' => 1,
            'cookieParams' => [
                'httpOnly' => true,
            ],
        ],`

Comment: Check if the `getId()` method of your class that implements `yii\web\IdentityInterface` actually returns proper id.

Comment: Also check if your cookies have proper sameSite option set.